# WOOCommerce error when I click shop link

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

http://afinderskeeper.com/

This is the site I am working on. Whenever I click "shop" I get this message that I have no idea what it means. The same thing happens when I try to search for anything in the main search bar, but not in the lower sidebar search bar.

I am able to view and add products in the backend, but I am not able to see them. I couldn't find someone with this same problem, just other issues. Remember, I'm not a coder so please be very specific if possible, thank you!

Error message:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'woocommerce_price_filter' not found or invalid function name in /home3/afinder2/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 199
Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home3/afinder2/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-query.php on line 353
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/afinder2/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:199) in /home3/afinder2/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 896
```

Comment: Looks to be an issue caused by incompatible plugins. Try turning off your plugins individually to see which one is the cause. And make sure all the plugins are up to date.

Comment: You were right! @RonanMurphy The plugin was "WooCommerce. Unfortunately that was a pretty necessary plugin. Any recommendations on similar plugins, or ways to resolve this without deactivating it? It is up to date also.

Comment: Can you uninstall woocommerce and reinstall it again with a fresh version?

Comment: Well, I tried that, but I get the same error message. Only now I still see the rest of the site but the error at the top of the page haha. Before, I saw just a white page with the error on it.
https://afinderskeeper.com/?s=hi&post_type=product @RonanMurphy

Comment: I assume you don't get that error when WooCommerce is not activated?

Comment: Exactly! It works fine with WooCommerce is deactivated. @RonanMurphy

Comment: What if you leave on WooCommerce and turn everything else off?

Comment: Woah I think that kind of works too, I was able to view my shop section for the first time, but I still get error message up in the header. @RonanMurphy

Comment: I was able to reactivate everything once again, and now it seems closer (still don't understand why simply reactivating can make such a difference haha). You can go take a look at the site as it currently is. All the pages seem okay, but the shop still has the error message up top, and also the top search bar throws errors at me too, when it used to give me search results. @RonanMurphy

Comment: Definitely looks to be some sort of plugin clash, especially if you're using the latest version of woocommerce. I don't think I have a solution for you though. Maybe edit your question to provide more information about the methods you've used.

Comment: Yea, I think it was definitely a plugin clash. I switched to "Ecwid" and everything is so far so good. I really appreciate all your help! @RonanMurphy